# Are women permitted to masturbate?

Tags: halacha, sexuality

From Tosfos in Niddah 13a it would seem like women are permitted to masturbate. However, I haven't seen any modern teshuves permitting or prohibiting it. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism_and_masturbation),

> The Halakhic attitude towards a female masturbation is found in the
>   opinions of the Ben Ish Chai,[9] who says that it is wrong because it
>   creates evil forces (Kelipos), and Rabbi Moshe Feinstein,[10] who
>   forbids it because it involves indulging in sexual fantasy about men,
>   which falls under the prohibition of forbidden thoughts, which are
>   forbidden for women as well. However, it does not carry the severity
>   of male masturbation, because it does not involve the release of seed.

Is it true that R' Moshe prohibited it? Are there any other modern Poskim that ruled on its permissibility?

Comment: Possible candidate for closure as per https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/how-modest-should-this-site-be/125#comment-206

Comment: i think there is an agadita (talmud) of disgusting behavior of a woman sitting on an idle

Comment: @JoelK You are welcome to vote to close the duplicate question as such if you feel like it. Please don't wait for moderators to act to make your voice heard!